# FEMA LOMA Data/WMS Availability?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, wms, united-states

Does anybody know where there might be some good/current FEMA data?

I am interested specifically in the LOMA data for Florida.

I have found a [WMS Service](https://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/wps/portal/NFHLWMS) that is hosted by FEMA but I'm having trouble actually bringing it into ArcMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The PDF tells** you how to consume the wms services

You need to know the layers and location you are interested in before you request the data.

**http://www.fema.gov/library/viewRecord.do?id=3292**

This mapviewer consumes that service.

https://hazards.fema.gov/wps/portal/mapviewer

This is a KML for Google Earth using that data:

http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&ved=0CD4QFjACOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.udfcd.org%2Fdownloads%2FGIS%2FNational%2520Flood%2520Hazard%2520Layer%2520%28FEMA%29.kmz&ei=40a-UO6iKcGmigKnkIHgAg&usg=AFQjCNFLnF1zMKLrlHi1x0SRyAgrEQx-TQ&cad=rja

Comment: Right, I can connect to a WMS Server and bring the service into ArcMap, my issue is that I am getting drawing errors whenever I zoom. My ultimate goal is to be able to reference the LOMA layer in my javascript app.